# Chat room privilege & view vote counts privilege gained too soon

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, reputation, privileges

Hi guys,

I've been around on stackoverflow for only a month or so and I've not got much reputation points. I just logged in on StackOverflow and I got a notification about having gained a new privilege.

[image: Screenshot:]

I thought 985 rep points was a weird amount to gain new privileges so I went to the privilege menu and saw this:

[image: Screenshot:]

I gained both privileges (create gallery chat rooms & view vote counts) with less than 1000 rep points. Is this a known bug? If so, I'm sorry for posting this, I couldn't find a question or remark on this case.

Regards and keep up the good work around here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1000 - 985 = 15, which is the amount of reputation received for getting an accepted answer. In other words, someone accepted your answer and then unaccepted it, so you had 1000 for a brief time. During that time, the system triggered the privileges notification. Even though you fell back under 1000, the notification was not revoked as this is said to be computationally expensive, so this is [status-bydesign](/questions/tagged/status-bydesign).

Comment: Thanks for your quick response. Makes great sense! Why didn't I think of that?